# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Express Js Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Facing this error in the express server TypeError 500 getting all values undefined.

```
500 TypeError: C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\apps\
    
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
   21| .col-md-12
    22| .posts
    > 23| h3= post.title
    24| p=post.body
    25| p tag:
    26| i=post.tag
    Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at eval (eval at (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:152:8), :221:59)
    at C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:153:35
    at Object.exports.render (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:197:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:233:18)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:218:21)
    at View.render (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:504:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render     (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:798:7)
    at C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\apps\blog\routes.js:64:14
    at callbacks (C:\Nodejs\NodejsBlog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in app.js `(server.js)` or your root file of the app to post req

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```